# Displaying Database info in rows of boxes/divs

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I want to display different messages from a database in rows of divs, it's for a portion of the site where people will be able to share stories. I want it to look like rows of post-it notes with the stories on them, then if they want to read more they can click on one and it goes to a detailed view of it. It's an ASP.net application, so I've been using VB for a lot of the other stuff.

It's a pretty simple database, with two-three fields (PK, Story, name) and I think it will use a page load event.  Just not sure how to access the data. Previously I dealt with displaying grids and rows, but now I want something more organic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an ASP guy, but the question seems a little vague. When pulling the data, you'll want to truncate the info from the database for the front page and then link to a full page with all of the info from that post.

For the display, you could use the help of the [jQuery masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at that now...It looks like it may work!